# Get methods for same URL with different data passed on in Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, web

So, I am trying to get different data at different scenarios for the same URL. Here is my code.

1st scenario:

```
app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
    res.render('upload', {data: 'a'});
});
```

2nd scenario:

```
res.redirect('/upload');
app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
    res.render('upload', {data: 'b'});
});
```

However, for some reason, it always executes the 1st scenario (only passes data: 'a'). How to prioritize each of the get method for a specific situation?

Comment: What is the difference between 1st and 2nd scenario?  What is the situation how can you check it?

Comment: @hurricane 1st scenario is just when we want to access the particular page. 2nd scenario is basically after I submitted a form, I want to redirect to the same page but with different content. I'm trying to access the different content by passing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can not use same string name for two different job.

You can do that with params or query. I have created an example with params for you. You can change switch case for your scenario.

**Params**

```
app.get('/upload/:scenario', function(req, res) {
  let resultData = {};
  switch (req.params.scenario) {
    case '1':
      resultData = {
        data: 'a'
      };
      break;
    case '2':
      resultData = {
        data: 'b'
      };
      break;
    default:
      resultData = {
        error: 'wrong id'
      };
  }
  res.render('upload', resultData);
  // http://localhost/api/upload/1 -> {"data":"a"}
  // http://localhost/api/upload/2 -> {"data":"b"}
});
```

Comment: What do yo mean by 'same string name for two different job'?